# Constructing DynamicArray with NULL in C++ Builder

Tags: c++, delphi, c++builder, builder, osc

I want to use the DelphiOSCUtils library in C++Builder.

The problem might be that it uses Generics, and C++Builder cannot handle Generics well.

The code inside the lib is like:

```pascal
USES ..., System.Generics.Collections; 

TOSCMessage = class(TOSCPacket)
private
  ...
public
  constructor Create(Address: string); overload;
  constructor Create(Bytes: TBytes); overload;
```

or

```
  TOSCPacket = class (TObject)
  private
   ...
  public
    constructor Create(Bytes: TBytes);
  end;
```

The HPP file generated is:

```cpp
class PASCALIMPLEMENTATION TOSCBundle : public TOSCPacket
{
    typedef TOSCPacket inherited;
private:
   ...
public:
    __fastcall TOSCBundle(System::DynamicArray<System::Byte> Bytes);
    __fastcall virtual ~TOSCBundle(void);
    __classmethod virtual TOSCPacket* __fastcall Unpack(System::DynamicArray<System::Byte> Bytes, int PacketOffset, int Count, System::Extended TimeTag = 0.000000E+00)/* overload */;
    /* Hoisted overloads: */    
public:
};
```

When I try to create a new TOSCMessage obj in C++

```cpp
TOSCBundle *bundle = new TOSCBundle(NULL);
```

I get an error:

> E2285 Could not find a match for 'TOSCBundle::TOSCBundle(int)'

Anyone has some pointers on how to fix this?

Comment: You talk about wanting to use `TOSCMessage`, but your C+++ code is using `TOSCBundle` instead, which has no relation to `TOSCMessage`.

Comment: sorry, I copied the wrong code, but the problem remains as the constructor signature is the same for both. (I will fix it soon)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue has nothing to do with Generics.

In C++, `NULL` is (usually) defined as an alias for an integer constant `0`.  But `TOSCBundle` does not have a constructor that accepts an `int` as input.  That is what the compiler is complaining about in your case.

The `TOSCBundle` constructor you are trying to call takes a [`System::DynamicArray<System::Byte>`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DynamicArray) object *by value*, so you have to pass it an actual `DynamicArray<Byte>` object to copy from.  However, unlike in Delphi where you can initialize a dynamic array from `nil`, in C++ you can't construct a `DynamicArray` from `NULL` (or even from `nullptr` in C++11 and later).  `DynamicArray` does not have a constructor for that.

So, to pass in an empty array, you will have to pass in a default-constructed `DynamicArray` object.  In this case, a temporary object will suffice, eg:

```cpp
TOSCBundle *bundle = new TOSCBundle(DynamicArray<Byte>());
```

Or, you can use the [`System::Sysutils::TBytes`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TBytes) alias (which is what the Delphi code you showed is using anyway):

```cpp
#include <System.SysUtils.hpp>

TOSCBundle *bundle = new TOSCBundle(TBytes());
```

Comment: The problem is not because of C++ itself, but because the `DynamicArray` class simply does not declare a constructor that accepts `NULL`/`nullptr` as input.